# [Katalon]: Regular expression for alphanumeric or null

Tags: regex, katalon

Hi anyone can guide me with this regular expression "alphanumeric or null"  in Katalon

This is what i add in "alphanumeric or null" and it will fail.
`assertTrue(value1.matches("^[0-9a-zA-Z]+\$")) | null`

May i know what is the actual way of writing regular expression for `"alphanumeric | null"`  value in Katalon?

Answer (score 0):

Your can write regex like this to verify your text:

```
WebUI.verifyMatch(yourText', '[^a-z ]*([.0-9])*\d')
```

and then when you want the test case to fail in case of empty value you can try:

```
WebUI.verifyNotEqual(yourElement.getAttribute('value'),'')
```

but when you want to verify that a html-element has a specific value, you can use:

```
WebUI.verifyEqual(yourElement.getAttribute('value'),'')
```